# Get vertical scroll position of next/previous waypoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm using the Waypoints plugin to create some fancy navigation on scroll. So that I can force the user to scroll to the next/previous `Waypoint`, I'm attempting to collect the vertical scroll position of the current, active and next Waypoint:

```js
$('.waypoint').waypoint(function(direction) {
    var 
        currentWpId     = this.element.id,
        currentWpPos    = $('#'+currentWpId).scrollTop(),
        nextWpPost      = $('#'+currentWpId).next().scrollTop(),
        prevWpPost      = $('#'+currentWpId).prev().scrollTop();

    console.log( currentWpPos );
    console.log( nextWpPost );
    console.log( prevWpPost );

});
```

Unfortunately jQuery's `scrollTop()` function returns `0` for all elements. After doing some reading I believe this is a result of the elements having `height: 100%;` which I cannot remove due to some other CSS requirements. (Although I'm not certain this is the root cause of the issue.) Is there a way around this?

After looking for some alternative solutions, I thought to myself the Waypoints 
plugin must know the values I'm trying to acquire to trigger a waypoint event! When looking at the `this` element, that indeed seems to be the case:

[image]

So, as an alternative, is there a way to acquire any array/object of all the Waypoint objects so I can grab these `triggerPoint` values?

Answer (score 0):

`scrollTop` returns the scroll value of a scrollable element. For example, `$(window).scrollTop()` returns how much a user has scrolled on the page. I believe you have this confused with the element's **position** in the document, which you can get by calling `.offset()`. Offset will return a an object with top and left coordinates. In the end, you're looking for `$(elem).offset().top`.